# Heroku + golang + mobiles => H13 errors?

Tags: heroku, go

On a golang service, I get some H13 (Heroku13 ?) errors these days ( max ~1% of requests ), but 100% of users calling the service are mobile apps.

Is it possible that if they lose connection it triggers an H13 error ?

Or is it only due to some of my code ?

Thx !

Comment: The description of H13 is `Connection closed without response` which mean the _server_ didn't write a response. You would need to instrument your code to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

H13 means the APP code is having a problem.
Taking too long or bloating up memory.

( asked a Heroku guy :) )